# Use multiple methods

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble using multiple methods in JavaScript. What would be the best way to construct something like this:

```
task.data(id).display();
task.data(id).edit();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to return a function from another function?  What is the "trouble" that you are having?  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible but little tricky

```
function data(id) {
  return {
    display: function () {
      alert('some message');
    }
  };
}
//now use it
data(id).display();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3uE6/)

---

For this to work in your context, you need to chain three methods